# What is causing the mapping failure in this Spring MVC app?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to get a very simple Spring @mvc app to work and I'm running into what appears to be a mapping error.

From web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>works</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>works</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TESTController  {
    private static Logger appLogger = Logger.getLogger("AppLogFile");

    public String serviceRequest(   Model model)
    {
        appLogger.info("======================= TESTController GET ===============================");
        model.addAttribute("returnString","TESTController handled the request") ;
        return "SingleStringView"; 
    }
```

works-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ami.dbconnect.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="TESTController" class="com.ami.dbconnect.controller.TESTController"></bean>

    <!-- view resolver not shown -->
```

The app is deployed to Tomcat 7 at /webapps/works.  The Tomcat file structure is:

```
webapps
    /works
        /WEB-INF
            /classes
            /lib
```

I'm trying to invoke the controller with the url: localhost:8080/works/test

In tomcat7-stdout I see:

1106 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'works' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.works]

1106 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'works': initialization completed in 728 ms

1106 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Servlet 'works' configured successfully

14068 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'works' processing GET request for [/works/test]

14071 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/works/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'works'

So my question (finally!):
Is Spring not recognizing the annotations in the controller?  If not, what could be wrong in this simple set up?

Thanks for any help or advice,
beeky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `@RequestMapping` annotation to your `serviceRequest` method.

`@RequestMapping` at class level may be used to specify common path prefix for all `@RequestMapping`-annotated of that class, but it doesn't take any effect without annotations at method level.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem is in the servlet mapping section?
Try to change:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>works</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/works/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And try again.